# How to compile several

Tags: linux, vim, makefile

I'm working on a larger project, but I'm struggling with splitting my tex-file into several tex-files, as I cannot seem to compile them into one pdf. I'm working from a Linux terminal trying to write a makefile that does this. I tried giving several tex-files as input with a single output but then it tried to compile them into several pdf's with the same name (and therefore threw an error at me).

```
mypdf.pdf : tex1.tex tex2.tex 
@ pdflatex $^
@ pdflatex $^
```

What should I do instead? I apologise if the question already exist, but in that case please link it, as I couldn't find it.

Comment: why not use the `latexmk` tool, it can run on multiple files, compiles enough times do references etc is up to date. In this case `pdflatex` i equivalent to `latexmk -pdf`

Comment: Since you want to combine several TeX files into a single resulting PDF, you have two possible routes I can think of: 1. combine them into a single document, that is use `\input` or `\include` in a main file to include the other files into that document. 2. compile each file  individually and combine the resulting PDFs into a single one with another tool or script (e.g., `pdfjoin` or `pdfunite`).

Comment: You can consider also use `bookdown`. In sort: you work in a project with several markdown files (that can include latex code) and Rstudio take care of the rest (i.e, mix all the subfiles in a single, file, convert that to latex and  build the pdf.